# Query not equal to multiple values

Tags: mysql

I have this bit of coding, could someone please help me with making the query correct, I thought i had it but I just receive a query error
Original code:

```
$q=$db->query("SELECT u.*,g.* FROM users u LEFT JOIN gangs g ON g.gangID=u.gang WHERE u.user_level != 2 $myf ORDER BY level DESC,userid ASC LIMIT 20");
```

My failed edit code:

```
$q=$db->query("SELECT u.*,g.* FROM users u LEFT JOIN gangs g ON g.gangID=u.gang WHERE u.user_level != 2 || WHERE u.user_level !=0 $myf ORDER BY level DESC,userid ASC LIMIT 20");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$q=$db->query("SELECT u.*,g.* FROM users u LEFT JOIN gangs g ON g.gangID=u.gang WHERE u.user_level != 2 || u.user_level !=0 $myf ORDER BY level DESC,userid ASC LIMIT 20");
```

You cannot put two where Clause

FYI: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//select.html

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer :D

Comment: If you don't want users with level 2 & 0, you should use 'AND' operator instead of "||"

Comment: I hope you have a prosperous new years :)

Answer (score 0):

instead

```
$q=$db->query("SELECT u.*,g.* FROM users u LEFT JOIN gangs g ON g.gangID=u.gang WHERE u.user_level != 2 || WHERE u.user_level !=0 $myf ORDER BY level DESC,userid ASC LIMIT 20");
```

You should, (remove 2nd where)

```
$q=$db->query("SELECT u.*,g.* FROM users u LEFT JOIN gangs g ON g.gangID=u.gang WHERE u.user_level != 2 || u.user_level !=0 $myf ORDER BY level DESC,userid ASC LIMIT 20");
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining what to do :)

Comment: what is the error you are getting? and just print your query so we come to know how you frame your query.

Comment: Venu answered my problem, thank you so much for your time though :) and for helping me, I wish you a prosperous new years.